# SQL sorting for INSERT

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I have a data set like this:

| LIST | ENAME | EDESC | NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALPHA | A | aa | 1 |
| ALPHA | B | bb | 2 |
| ALPHA | C | cc | 3 |
| GAMMA | M | mm | 1 |
| GAMMA | N | nn | 2 |
| OMEGA | Y | yy | 0 |
| OMEGA | Z | zz | 1 |

NUM is the priority of the 'E's or elements of each LIST

The logic for NUM (which I can't control) is that it orders elements smallest to largest, but the first element does not have to be NUM = 0. For example, you can see that OMEGA's elements are Y=0 and Z=1 while GAMMA's are M=1 and N=2 - the system considers these orderings equivalent.

This data comes from a query from a system whose data structure I can't control, but I want to put this data into my own database but in the following format:

| LIST | E1NAME | E1DESC | E2NAME | E2DESC | E3NAME | E3DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALPHA | A | aa | B | bb | C | cc |
| GAMMA | M | mm | N | nn |  |  |
| OMEGA | Y | yy | Z | zz |  |  |

Can this be done with using SQL INSERT into a MySQL/MariaDB database?

The data is being pulled from the source via Python, and the result is parsed using Pandas - perhaps there is a way to do it in Pandas such that the subsequent SQL INSERT into my DB isn't as complicated?

Comment: Are lists limited to a maximum of three elements?

Comment: You can easily do this in SQL, but I can't figure out what the question is.

Comment: @TheImpaler yes Lists are limited to three elements, but they don't have to contain three elements, they also cannot contain zero elements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my apologies for not stating the question more clearly; how do I accomplish this using SQL INSERT statements into a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select list,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ename end) as ename_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then edesc end) as edesc_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ename end) as ename_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then edesc end) as edesc_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then ename end) as ename_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then edesc end) as edesc_3
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by list order by num) as seqnum
      from dataset d
     ) d
group by list;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f34126/3/0

Your query doesn't quite work, notice the OMEGA result set, it does not contain all the values required (The 'Y', 'yy' data does not appear in the result).

Comment: @RobertPhillips . . . I fixed the answer.  In fact, this is often done using `row_number()`.  I just thought that `num` had the necessary sequential information.

Comment: The updated query doesn't work > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f34126/9

Comment: @RobertPhillips . . . It requires MySQL 8.0 (which has been out for about 3 years now).  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=543db31ebc32185b8eb2d8027c2665d6.

Answer (score 0):

#### `factorize`

```
num = df.groupby('LIST').NUM.transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x, sort=True)[0]) + 1
new_df = df.assign(NUM=num).set_index(['LIST', 'NUM']) \
           .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1, ascending=[True, False])

new_df.columns = [f'{b[0]}{a}{b[1:]}' for a, b in new_df.columns]

new_df

      E1NAME E1DESC E2NAME E2DESC E3NAME E3DESC
LIST                                           
ALPHA      A     aa      B     bb      C     cc
GAMMA      M     mm      N     nn    NaN    NaN
OMEGA      Y     yy      Z     zz    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: In this output why is 'LIST' not a header like 'E1NAME'... are? Is it treating the whole column of 'LIST' as an Index for the dataframe?

Comment: Yes. Use reset_index